# Joomla encodes my link targets inside my component

Tags: joomla

Searched for a while now.
I'm using newest Joomla Version 3.3.6 (with Gantry Framework) and am trying to create an own component for it.
The problem I have is: I need to use links that contain special characters like spaces.
Joomla seems to encode or rewrite these links and replaces the special characters with HTML code.

Example out of my components view file (hard coded):

```
<a href="index.html#test like" title="test like">test like</a>
```

Becomes when opened in frontend:

```
<a href="index.html#test%20like" title="test like">test like</a>
```

I'm now looking for the function that does this "trick" to hack this behaviour out of it,
but can't find it yet.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I believe this could possibly be a Gantry feature to make URL's safe. But as @Tims mentioned, do not try to change this behavior.

Comment: Hi Lodder,
thank you very much for your comment.
I also searched in the Gantry sourcecode but couldn't find a solution.
I understand that it is a security feature, but I really want to know which function changes my hard coded links.

Comment: That would be hard to tell. Gantry is very big and has hundreds of files. Gantry of course was only a guess as it's not something Joomla does by default.

Comment: Hi Lodder,
thank you very much.
Yes, Gantry is very big ^^ I searched whole yesterday but couldn't find anything and I can't be sure that it is really Gantry that changes the links.
Problem is, that the project is located on a server where I can't debug the way I want to.
So I have to more or less just search and follow the values line by line which takes like forever ^^
But anyways, thanks for your suggestion and your comments !

Comment: You could always try doing a mess find in your text editor. I always use Notepad++ so do "CTRL + F" and select "find in files",  set the directory to the root of your Joomla installation and the string you want to search for is `urlencode(` << Note there is a opening bracket but no closing bracket

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and already searched for urlencode, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, replace, etc.
Also with a lot of wildcards and different wordings.
But no luck so far :(

Comment: I am having a similar problem, [Joomla is just acting up weired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520192/javascript-is-forcing-my-concat-plus-to-20)

Answer (score 2):

**Spaces are unsafe characters in URLs/URIs** and therefore need to be encoded.  This is because significant sequences of spaces may be lost in some uses (especially multiple spaces).

When a space is encoded it becomes `%20` in hex.  This is behaviour that is correct and you **should not try to change** as it will make your URL/URI unsafe.

For more information about unsafe and reserved characters check out the following links.

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Comment: Hi Tims,
thank you very much for your answer.
I only use hard coded links and I need this feature only for spaces after the "#" like in my example.
I understand, that this is a security function and that it is there to protect the system, but I still want to know which function in which file does this change.

Comment: This is not a security function.  It is a *specification*.  You should not be changing the correct behaviour of joomla to allow for your incorrect use of URLs.  Fix your anchor links instead.  A standard way is to use `_` or `-` instead of spaces.

Comment: Hi Tims, thank you for your comment. After another day of searching for this function, I think I will have to change the anchor links. Thank you for all the information.