# Joomla! is forcing my concat plus '+' to "%20"

Tags: javascript, php, apache, joomla

I have this Multi-line string comprised of mostly html, so I decided to use single inverted commas as delimiters.

To keep it succinct, I have removed much of the html from the string to just focus on the error part.

```
jQuery("#myModal .modal-content").html('<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Duplicate Entry Found!</h4></div>' +
      '<a type="button" href="index.php?layout=studentprofile&id=' + studentid +'" target="_blank">View Student Profile</a>' );
```

What is happening is that the **server is urlencoding the code and removing the plus signs `+` and adding `%20`in its place**.

If I am writing the concatenation like `...studentprofile&id=' + studentid +"` (ie. with spaces) the output is `...id='%20%20%20studentid%20%20%20'"`

And If I **remove all whitespaces** from between the strings and the plus sign, like  `...studentprofile&id='+studentid+"` then the output becomes `...id='%20studentid%20'"`

One interesting observation is this is only happening for single inverted commas, and If I just switch the commas it gets back to working correctly.

Other things which I'd like to add is this code used to work flawlessly on previous LAMP installations, but I have recently upgraded the whole stack so don't know if the the `webserver` or the `php` language, or even my framework which btw, is `Joomla!` is introducing this behavior.

**One more discovery:** This is only happening for the pluses around the `studentid` variable, rest of all the string with their pluses is working perfect.

OK, I seem to be onto something here, It clearly is Joomla!'s fault now, Found another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160537/joomla-encodes-my-link-targets-inside-my-component).

Comment: Are you inserting this code via a code editor.. that makes a difference.

Comment: @norcaljohnny No, this code is inside a custom component view-layout.

Comment: So you want that part of the url to say literally `id+studentid+`?

Comment: Joomla works very hard to get you to produce correctly specified outputs including urls.  In the question you linked the person was trying to create an invalid url since a url cannot contain a space.  THis is why in Joomla you will see that in aliases the spaces are replaced with hyphens, just as one example.   Can you please show an example of exactly what you want the final URL to look like?

Comment: @9kSoft Please show more of your script.  It feels like this is being caused by the _way_ you are delivering this snippet.  Is this inside of `$document->addScriptDeclaration()`?  You can see that your js variable `studentid`, despite your obvious attempt to concat it, is not being replaced by its value.  Let's not blame Joomla too hastily.

Comment: Great point, @Elin .  If the intention was to literally use `id+studentid+`, it would be simpler to write: `href="index.php?layout=studentprofile&id=+studentid+"`.

Comment: You can have two id values if you need to make two queries I guess, but normally you would just build all that into your model.

Answer (score 1):

Try the fllowing snippet. It does work:

```js
var studentid = '2';

console.log(
'<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Duplicate Entry Found!</h4></div>' +
      '<a type="button" href="index.php?layout=studentprofile&id=' + studentid +'" target="_blank">View Student Profile</a>'
);
```

Comment: It most probably is, Joomla! being itself :)

Comment: @Martin The issue is not with the task being done, it is a matter of _how_ it is being delivered by the user to Joomla.

Comment: Where are you thinking  + studentid +  comes from and what do you think it represents?  Without understanding more it's hard to say, but basically I think you are misunderstanding some fundamentals of building strings from a combination of variables and fixed string in PHP.  You should look at some examples of links build in models or the article views. You can see these in your template manager.

Comment: Wait you are doing this in the console?